# Android libGDX no background Sprite after state changed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to adjust the texture in my game to diffrent screens sizes, so I try to add `ExtendViewport` into my `viewport`, but Whenever I try change the states the background is not loaded. For the first time everything works fine, but whenever I try to set another state Ive got blank screen (I try with the same State instance to exclude the code errors)

**STATE**

```
public abstract class State {

protected OrthographicCamera camera;
protected  GameStateManager gsm;
protected Viewport viewport;
public State(GameStateManager gsm) {
    this.gsm = gsm;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(GAME_SIZE_WIDTH * aspectRatio, GAME_SIZE_HEIGHT, camera);
    viewport.apply();

    camera.position.set(GAME_SIZE_WIDTH / 2, GAME_SIZE_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
     }
public  abstract void handleInput();
public abstract void update(float dt);
public abstract void render (SpriteBatch sb);
public abstract void dispose();
public abstract void resize(int width, int height) ;
}
```

**Menu State**

```
public class MenuState extends State{


    private Sprite background;
    private Sprite playButton;

    public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);

        background =new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("back.jpg")));
        background.setSize(GAME_SIZE_WIDTH,GAME_SIZE_HEIGHT);
        background.setPosition(0,0);

        playButton=new Sprite(new Texture("play.png"));
        playButton.setSize(40,30);
        playButton.setPosition(GAME_SIZE_WIDTH/2-playButton.getWidth()/2,GAME_SIZE_HEIGHT/2-playButton.getHeight()/2);
    }



    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        background.draw(sb);
        playButton.draw(sb);
        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        playButton.getTexture().dispose();
        background.getTexture().dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width,height);
        camera.position.set(GAME_SIZE_WIDTH / 2, GAME_SIZE_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));}
    }
    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
    }
}
```

**GameStateManager**

```
public class GameStateManager {

private Stack<State> states;

public GameStateManager() {
    states=new Stack<State>();

}

public void push(State state){
    states.push(state);
}
public void pop(){
    states.pop().dispose();
}
public void set(State state){
    states.pop().dispose();
    states.push(state);
}
public void update(float dt){
    states.peek().update(dt);
}

public void render(SpriteBatch sb){
    states.peek().render(sb);
}
public  void resize(int width, int height){
    states.peek().resize(width,height);
}}
```

Comment: how you change your state(transition from one state to another) ?

Comment: Using GameStateManager instance. Ive holding each States on the stack and whenever I want to set the the new state i pop it from stack and dispose it and then creating new one and push it on the stack. That approach work fine when I did not using viewports and using Texture instead of sprite, but I want to upgrade me app to handle diffrent screen sizes so I decided to use viewports. I put my logic in the question if you like to watch it.

Comment: what do you mean by **background is not loaded.** Each time you need to create  new State object and push into stack of your State.

Comment: I mean that I run the game and have the background image and button image  on it. Whenever I clicked on the screen it should create the new state with identicall background and button, but Ive got the empty screen without any drawing on it. look at my code I created new state and put on the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is simple, you're not updating viewport of new State so update that with your screen width and height.

First time when Game Start resize method of `State` called by `ApplicationListener` class in this way.

`ApplicationListener`'s `resize(,)` -> `GameStateManager`'s `resize(,)` -> `State`'s `resize(,)`

After that `resize( , )` of State or GameStateManager never called.

so simply change `set()` method of your `GameStateManager`.

```
public void set(State state){
    state.resize((int)states.peek().viewport.getScreenWidth(),(int)states.peek().viewport.getScreenHeight());
    states.pop().dispose();
    states.push(state);
}
```